# conditional use of Sys.sleep() inside as_mapper()

Tags: r, purrr

I'm downloading and renaming photos through an API, and only 30 photos can be downloaded per minute. I'd like to pause the downloads once I reach 30, 60, 90 photos etc. as a work around.

Currently I'm using as_mapper() from the purrr package to download the photos. I have a dataframe containing the photo url and photo destination:

```
# download function
download_name_photos <- as_mapper(
      
      ~GET(
        ..1, # photo url
        add_headers("Authorization" = paste("Bearer", token)),
        write_disk(
          ..2, # photo destination
          overwrite = TRUE
        )
      )
    )
    
# now download photos using pwalk()
photo_df %>%
   pwalk(download_name_photos)
```

Is there a way to include `Sys.sleep()` within my `as_mapper()` function so it only sleeps at photo 30, photo 60, etc. by adding a photo number column to my data frame? I'm picturing a data frame like this that uses the photo count (n) to pause things:

```
tribble(
  ~photo_url, ~photo_destination, ~n,
  'https:://blah-blah-1', 'photo1.jpg', '1',
  'https:://blah-blah-2', 'photo2.jpg', '2',
  'https:://blah-blah-3', 'photo3.jpg', '3'
)
```